# Cannot find type definition file for '@types' Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3, angular5

My app's been build and running perfectly for a month, suddenly I got an error of the following

```
Error: Failed to transpile TypeScript
```

It is running with the following tsconfig.json file

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
  },
```

now if I add 
`type:[]` in compilerOption then it's built and running properly as it was before. As far as I concern that is not the good solution rather I must say it's a temporary solution to build, while the error is encountered.
Walk me through the proper solution.